# I have reduced an object of arrays but cant ng-repeat the values I received?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[image]I have the values I need in an array after reducing them from another array but can't seem to figure out how to work with them in an ng-repeat?

```
var data = [{ ticketId: 1, Category: "Driver", CategoryID: 29, SubCategory:"Monitor", SubCategoryID: 31 }, { ticketId: 2, Category: "Driver", CategoryID: 29, SubCategory: "Monitor", SubCategoryID: 31 }, { ticketId: 3, Category: "Hardware", CategoryID: 11, SubCategory: "Monitor", SubCategoryID: 32 }, { ticketId: 4, Category: "Hardware", CategoryID: 11, SubCategory: "phone", SubCategoryID: 13 }],
count = data.reduce(function (r, a) {
    r[a.Category] = r[a.Category] || {};
    r[a.Category][a.SubCategory] = (r[a.Category][a.SubCategory] || 0) + 1;
    return r;
}, {});

  document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(count, 0, 4) + '</pre>');

   Example: 
  <div ng-controller="controller as vm">
  <ul ng-repeat="t in vm.array">
  <li>{{t.data}}</li>
  </ul>
  </div>

  angular.module("app").controller("controller", function(){  
     var main = this;

       main.getCategoriesCount = function () {
                var data = main.openTickets;

     var count = data.reduce(function (r, a) {
          r[a.Category] = r[a.Category] || {};
          r[a.Category][a.SubCategory] = (r[a.Category][a.SubCategory] || 0)      + 1;
          return r;
      }, {});
                 main.array = count;
            }

       }
```

Comment: Assign them to a `$scope` variable - and use `ngRepeat` on that in the view, not `document.write`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.I included the document.write so that you can see the data that is outputting. I tried what you said but once I write ng-repeat= "t  in array" I don't have anything to access the data inside the array with the t. [{Application: Object},
{Database Installation: Object}]

Comment: How are you assigning the data to `t`? - Could you post your controller definition above as well

Comment: What shows on the page.. unparsed `{{t.data}}` or an empty list?

Comment: the .data was just a filler. If I had [{name: "Susan", lastName: "Kite"}] I would do t.name. With the data I am getting back I have [{Susan: {Kite: 21}}]

Comment: So you can see the data in the view, it's just not formatted how you want it?

Comment: Right, now its just setup as {{t}} which show the whole object in the view

Comment: @tymejv https://jsfiddle.net/bg9aqgex/

Comment: I would like the fiddle to say Hardware 2 and toggle Phone 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For repeating the elements of an object (as opposed to an array), use:

```
<ul ng-repeat="(key, value) in object">
```

It turns out that in both this and your [other related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34731682/i-have-an-array-of-100-objects-with-properties-of-category-and-subcategory-and-n) you have an "XY problem".  You have chosen a particular data structure that you think can represent your data, but it's actually not the right one for the job, because it's not practical to store the counts for the top level category as a property, and at the same time store the children as properties too.

Instead, I recommend a more "nested" approach:

```
$scope.counts = data.reduce(function(r, o) {
    var cat = o.Category;
    var sub = o.SubCategory;

    r[cat] = r[cat] || { count: 0, children: {} }
    r[cat].count++;

    r[cat].children[sub] = r[cat].children[sub] || { count: 0 }
    r[cat].children[sub].count++;
    return r;
}, {});
```

This will give each entry an explicit `count` property and then a separate `children` property, the keys of which are the sub-category's names.

You can then use two nested `ng-repeat` directives:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="(cat, info1) in counts"> {{cat}} {{info1.count}} 
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="(sub, info2) in info1.children">
        {{sub}} {{info2.count}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/ezn48htm/

Comment: I think you want to make a list item for each item in `vm.array` so repeat the `li` elements: `<ul><li ng-repeat="(key, value) in vm.array"></li></ul>`

Comment: @FrankvanWijk  Yes, that's probably correct - I was only addressing the use of `ng-repeat` on an object, not the OP's HTML

Comment: <ul ng-repeat="(key, value) in vm.array">
<li>
{{key}}
<ul>
<li>{{value}}</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>

Comment: @Rethabile well, we can't tell for sure what output you actually want, and I'd be slightly concerned about the doubly-nested object, since that indicates that you need _another_ `ng-repeat="(key2, value2)"` inside the first.

Comment: Thank you for the example. "name" and "kite" are not properties I have:       [{Susan: {Kite: 21}}, {Mike: {John: 25}}, {John:{Snow: 23}},{Wilson:{Johnson: 28}}]

Comment: @Rethabile I don't know where those came from, perhaps someone else's comment?

Comment: @Rethabile and?  You appear to be calculating the number of times that each category and subcategory appear.  The code in your fiddle only counts the top level category, and isn't the same as this question.

Comment: I get the count of all subcategories for a Category and then I get the count of SubCategories by them selves. I cant display the data I am getting back.

Comment: Ill add the document write again so that you can see the data

Comment: No, don't - I've seen the data, it's just that your code and your fiddle are not consistent.  Take a look at my own fiddle to see correct usage for `ng-repeat` with an object.

Comment: @alnitak if you add:   document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(count, 0, 4) + '</pre>'); under $scope.array you can see the data that is returned

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100484/discussion-between-rethabile-and-alnitak).

Comment: The black boxes should list the categories and its count and when you click on the black box it should show the subcategories and its count

Comment: yes, well unfortunately you omitted *any* detail about how the data maps to the desired HTML from your question...   In any event, you'll need two separate objects for that - it'll confuse things if you both include counts *and* subcategories in the same object.

Comment: @Rethabile ultimately you have the wrong data structure - you would be better with an array of `[ { name: <category_name>, count: n, children: [ ... ] }]` where `children` is a nested array of the same structure.    That however is an entirely separate question from the one you asked.

Comment: @alnitak http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34731682/i-have-an-array-of-100-objects-with-properties-of-category-and-subcategory-and-n

Comment: Ah, an "XY Problem".  You have chosen a data structure to represent the counts, and asked how to produce that.  Unfortunately, it's the wrong data structure for producing the desired output.

Comment: @alnitak Stackoverflow suggest not leaving thank you commits but until they find another way or until I have enough points to add to others this is my option. Thank you so much for taking the time to help. With the combined answers it solved the goal I was trying to reach.

Comment: @Rethabile you're welcome, and hopefully you also learned something about how to figure out what your actual problem is, not the one you think you have ;)

Comment: @Rethabile To answer your question "Is the above right?" No, it isn't but it seems your question is answered now. I am totally lost in this conversation. Next time please isolate your problem in a simple example, show what you tried and tell what you try to solve.

Comment: @FrankvanWijk ultimately 1.  the OP's data structure was a poor choice for the task at hand  2.  he needed nested `ng-repeat` directives, 3.  he was also using the wrong syntax for `ng-repeat` for objects